# Finding table name in HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel

I've had a code that pulls mutual fund return data from a table on Marketwatch.com's website, but it seems they've changed the page, and the name of the table, and I can't seem to figure it out and/or pull the data.

An example would be:  [marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vfinx](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/vfinx)

Looks to me like the table name `class = "table.table.table--primary.align--right.c6.j-totalReturns"`

Doesn't work. I tried just "totalReturns", but that didn't do it either.

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Edit:
So here's a little more of the code I was using

```
Dim oHTML       As Object
Dim oTable      As Object
Dim x           As Long
Dim Y           As Long
Dim vData       As Variant

Set oHTML = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

With CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
.Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/" & 
ActiveCell.Value, False
.send
oHTML.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

For Each oTable In oHTML.Getelementsbytagname("table")
If oTable.classname = "fundstable" Then
    ReDim vData(1 To oTable.Rows.Length, 1 To oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length)

        For x = 1 To UBound(vData)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
            vData(x, Y) = oTable.Rows(x - 1).Cells(Y - 1).innertext
        Next Y
        Next x

    With ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
    .Resize(UBound(vData), UBound(vData, 2)).Value = vData
    End With
Exit For
End If
Next oTable

Next Z
```

So on the sheet, I would have several tickers spaced ten rows apart down below, and my macro would go down, pull the chart for each one, and then I have cells referencing the data being pulled. Again, my only problem is the table isn't named "fundstable" any more.
And again, your method works, but I can't get it to work as cleanly - i.e. the inserting of the data starts adding columns (and therefore moving other cells around). Ideas?

Comment: Hey John - Thanks again for looking into this for me. Your solution works perfectly.  Crazy thing is, I still couldn't figure out why I couldn't get my original code to work, so I fooled around with it more, and I guess I must have just had an extra space or typo in there somehow, because somehow, now "table.table.table--primary.align--right.c6.j-totalReturns"  DOES work!  So now at least I have two solutions! Thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will create a new sheet, put the querytable on the new sheet, copy the querytable to your old sheet (without pushing anything aside) and then delete the new sheet.  Alternatively you could keep the new sheet with the query table and "querytable.refresh" it when ever needed.  Doing so should update the sheet where you copied it to also.

```
    Sub GetDataFromInternetFirstTimeAndCreateNewSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim actSh As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   Destroy this sheet if exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MarketWatch_Query").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set actSh = ActiveSheet
    '   Create the new sheet and name it
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "MarketWatch_Query"

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/gdow" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
'  You can get specific tables only by changing xlEntirePage to the following
'           .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables  'xlAllTables 'xlEntirePage
'           .WebTables = "1,2"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    numRows = ws.QueryTables(1).ResultRange.Rows.Count
    numCols = ws.QueryTables(1).ResultRange.Columns.Count
    ws.Activate
    '   Copy the table to any sheet you want to and it will not push anything aside
    '   However it will overwrite cells so put it somewhere that nothing will be overwritten
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(numRows, numCols)).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(10, 1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    '   Then destroy the new sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MarketWatch_Query").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry - I just got around to getting the code I had copied and editing my question with it, without realizing you just put this together. I'll try this out now. Thanks again for checking it out, and for putting this together!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700058-visual-basic-applications-code-extract-html-table-data-worksheet.html):

once you get the data you can format it any way you like

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '

    '
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/gdow" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
'  You can get specific tables only by changing xlEntirePage to the following        
'           .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables  'xlAllTables 'xlEntirePage
'           .WebTables = "1,2"
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and sorry for my delayed response!

Comment: This code is working, but the problem I'm having is when I do multiple funds. The code "inserts" the table into the page, which is bumping everything over 6 columns (the width of the table). Is there a way to just copy and paste the data into preset destination cells? The code I had come up with before used WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1, which, (if I understand it correctly), basically created an object, grabbed the table, and then copied the table elements and pasted them in the desired location from the object. I'll copy some of my current code and maybe you can tell me what's best.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is by putting the query table on another sheet and copy it to your original sheet with the code I made above.  Copying it from the new sheet into your original sheet doesn't push anything aside.  At least it didn't for me.

Comment: Hey John - Old thread here, but I had a quick question. I ran into a problem with this code again. Seems Marketwatch doesn't like me pulling from their page any more. Now, when I debug print my response text from my query, I'm seeing that Marketwatch sees I'm a bot and has inserted a Captcha. I'm assuming no way around that?